# Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '01/26/2015'. Current value: '12/27/2014'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the `error` on the below html template:

```
<p *ngIf="startDate()"><span [innerHTML]="startDate()"></span> to 
        <span [innerHTML]="endDate()"></span></p>
```

Below is my `startDate` fn

```
startDate = () => {
  if (this.session.history[0]) {
      return this.session.history[0].date;
   } else {
      return "";
  }
};
```

I looked into some threads, but not able to understand the problem or solution. 
[Angular2 - Expression has changed after it was checked - Binding to div width with resize events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930183/angular2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-binding-to-div-width-wi)

Ths solution says we need to use `ngAfterViewInit`() here, but i am not really getting it.

Comment: what is `this.session.history`? Looks like some function sets up `this.session.history[0].date` to some other value during the template rendering

Comment: @smnbbrv: this is a value which i get from API, but that happens before the component is rendered...

Comment: Without the whole component code and, I'm afraid, the whole app there is no chance somebody can help you. Ideally you should create a plunkr